# echo or return from a function

Tags: php, html

I have a function which echos out common code for a web page. If I do the code like this:

```
echo '<tr>'; 
CSCell("{$row['home_team']}/{$row['home_team']}",'home_home',$row, 1);
echo '</tr><tr>'; 
CSCell("{$row['home_team']}/Draw",'home_draw',$row, 1);
echo '</tr><tr>';
```

It works without issue. If I do it like this:

```
echo '<tr>' . CSCell("{$row['home_team']}/{$row['home_team']}",'home_home',$row, 1) . '</tr>';
echo '<tr>' . CSCell("{$row['home_team']}/Draw",'home_draw',$row, 1) . '</tr>';
```

It outputs an additional empty row for each line of code. Presumably it initially echos <tr> then the function outputs data then it returns `null` (because no return specified) then it begins the echo again (without re-calling the function & prints <tr>*empty string*</tr>).

How to stop it re-echoing the `tr` HTML? The function only contains `td` echo data?

I'm too lazy to make it return now because of the other parts it is referenced in where it needs to echo.  How to modify the function so it can be used to echo and return?

Comment: Have it `return` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Note that with the first method you have an unclosed row <tr> at the end of your output

Comment: functions should always use `return`, never `echo`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: I'm too lazy to make it return now because of the other parts it is referenced in. Guess I'll just do the individual lines for tr tags

Comment: @nogad so PHP has no notion of a real procedure at all?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "real procedure"

Comment: @nogad a procedure. Seems PHP only has functions and so always expects a return value. No procedures in PHP

Comment: no idea how you come to this conclusion, but it its of topic here.

Comment: @nogad It's exactly the topic here. The title of this question asks as such -_- even the examples of "procedures" online have return clauses (although ultimately returning null) and continue to use the function keyword

Comment: your arguing about PHP, not your code. that is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already relying on the output in other code, just add a fifth parameter to the function to tell it to `echo` or `return`:

```
function CSCell($a, $b, $c, $d, $return=false) {
    // build $output
    if($return) { return $output; }
    echo $output;
}
```

Then call it with `$return = true`:

```
echo '<tr>' . CSCell("{$row['home_team']}/Draw", 'home_draw', $row, 1, true) . '</tr>';
```

If you can't modify the function, then build a wrapper and buffer the output and return.  I don't know what the function looks like so you need to check the arguments or rely on the `CSCell()` function to validate them:

```
function _cscell($a, $b, $c, $d) {
    ob_start();
    CSCell($a, $b, $c, $d);
    return ob_end_clean();
}
```

Then call the wrapper function:

```
echo '<tr>' . _cscell("{$row['home_team']}/Draw", 'home_draw', $row, 1) . '</tr>';
```